# Latex Table of Contents Links to Wrong Section

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texmaker

I have a section followed by a table of contents like so:

```
\section{Section1}
ABC.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{Section2}
DEF.
\section{Section3}
GHI.
```

My issue is that the "Table of Contents" and "List of Figures" entries in the table of contents link (in the generated pdf) to the wrong place in the file. They both link to the first section section on page 1. The entry in the table is correct (TOC says page 2 and LOF says page 3), but the link goes to the wrong place.

Comment: May be, the preamble etc. can be added so its easy to compile for others.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'll need to use the `\phantomsection` command:

```
\section{Section1}
ABC.
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{Section2}
DEF.
\section{Section3}
GHI.
```

See [the hyperref manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html).

Comment: This only works as long as the table of contents and the list of figures don't span more than a single page. Otherwise, the links will point to the last page of the listings.

Comment: I've suggested a different solution that should work either way.

Comment: I had to add `\providecommand\phantomsection{}` to my preamble.

Comment: I can confirm that, as @Noah said, the references still work as expected even when the lists span more than a single page.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this for the bibliography, list of tables or list of figures,

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

should fix it, without the wrong-page problems. Otherwise, I havent come across a better solution than \phantomsection with \addcontentsline.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the fact that `\tableofcontents` inserts a page break before writing the contents. Hence, your PDF bookmark will point to the page before. Depending on your document class, you can manually insert a number of `\newpage` commands to keep `\tableofcontents` from adding another. One or two should be sufficient.

I know, it is a hacky solution, and there might exist a package to solve the problem, but this is how I work around the problem.

Comment: That didn't work, I added 1-3 new pages and it still links to the beginning of the previous section. I did the compile twice.